# Would it be possible to use my DSL router in another house?

Tags: networking, dsl, broadband

I have a broadband connection and a DSL router. I have to go to another house for a couple of weeks. Both the houses have the same telephone connection. So would it be possible to use the DSL Router in the other house? Would there be any extra charges? I know all my usernames and passwords.

Comment: define "same telephone connection": is it the same cable? is it the exact same connection? or just the same company offering the service?

Comment: As long as the phone line in the second house is connected to a DSL counterpart in the telephone switch station the DSL router will not work because there is no DSL on the line.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically it should - you probably will have to change the PPPoE details from the router's connection page.

Practically, some operators *might* bind the routers to the telephone line/number. I've never seen this, only heard reports of this but there should be no reason why you can't use them

Comment: My current ISP uses a method like this. My router is bound to my line (very inconvenient and impossible for me to use an other one as stand-alone).

Comment: Aftermarket modem/routers allow their MAC address to be replaced.  So if you know the original MAC address, you can clone it on a new modem/router, and the ISP should not notice the swap.

Answer (score 1):

If the credentials you are referring to are the ones used to establish the connection and no MAC address checks are done (rare) it should work.

I have used a connection registered on line A on a different line B myself. Even though my ISP never noticed, they asked me to revert the change immediately when I told them.